# Security of Android assets folder

Tags: android, security, assets

Is the assets folder only accessible to the app or can the user see it too? For my app I want to store a credential certificate and video files on local storage but I am not sure how to hide these items from the users. The assets folder seems like the only choice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `assets/` folder of an application is readable by any other application. While the user does not have direct access to it, all it would take is some application to provide such access. For all I know, there is an asset explorer app out on the Market.

Also, note that the `assets/` folder is not modifiable at runtime, which sounds like something you may be seeking.

Comment: Just to add on to the response - Given the open nature of Android you cannot assume any folder is secure.  If you want to store information securely, you'll have to encrypt it (and even then, that's only secure if the user is providing a password; it doesn't mean complete security if your own code is what unlocks it, it just means someone will have a fun time examining byte code to get at your password).