# Library to encryption and decryption resources

Tags: android, security, encryption, android-resources

My question is related to following questions.

1. [Security of Android assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406581/security-of-android-assets-folder)
2. [Assets Security in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030083/assets-security-in-android)

Basically the application which I am making has some mp3 resources which I wanted to secure. So is there library which work on android to encrypt and then decrypt resources especially mp3 files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that any method of encryption that you use will need storing the key to decrypt the encrypted data. This key will have to be available to your application and thus to anyone who has access to your application. By encrypting the data you change the problem of hiding your data to the problem of hiding your key and there is pretty much no way around it. The most you can do is to make your data harder to read but it can't be made impossible to read, unless you run your application on a trusted computing platform, as I said in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275581/android-resources-security/5275702#5275702).