# how we can remove a file from the assets folder at runtime in android?

Tags: android

how we can remove a file from the assets folder at runtime? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is a discussion about it:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg16172.html

Seems like the apk is read only and you wont be able to modify it.

Edit:

Check commonswares answer here:

[Security of Android assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406581/security-of-android-assets-folder)

He is saying the same thing, you can't modify it at runtime.