# Can an app delete its own internal resources?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how we can remove a file from the assets folder at runtime in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398523/how-we-can-remove-a-file-from-the-assets-folder-at-runtime-in-android)

I am trying to find a way to delete an internal resource after an app installs.  More specifically, I have a zip file included in the apk, that I unzip to the SD Card when the app is first run.  But then want to delete the now unneeded zip file (the purpose being to save the user internal phone memory).

I access the zip file with,

```
Resources resources = this.getResources(); 
InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.assets);
```

But am uncertain how to then delete the resource (if even possible).

I know one may ask why not simply install the app to SD Card at download.  But the app includes a screen widget, and installing apps to the SD Card and using a screen widget is problematic.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: What resources do you want to delete ?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398523/how-we-can-remove-a-file-from-the-assets-folder-at-runtime-in-android

Comment: Thank you, Sergey.  I think that answers it.  "The .apk is read-only, and can not be modified."  We will look for a different solution.