# How can i remove the file from assets in android application after re-installing the application?

Tags: android

There is requirement that I need to delete a file from assets when my application is re-installed. And this file must remain same in every launch. How can I do this?

Comment: When you reinstal you add the new assets folder so the old assets folder doesn't matter... The file will be the same as it is packed inside your assets of your app.

Answer (score 2):

I think, `assets/` folder is not modifiable at runtime, So you can't. (Hope I am wrong on this) :-)

Look at this discussion [Delete assets at runtime](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2d71e26663533edc#)

Comment: Also look at this SO question [how we can remove a file from the assets folder at runtime in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398523/how-we-can-remove-a-file-from-the-assets-folder-at-runtime-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

**The `\assets` directory is read-only**, therefore his content can´t be modified.

Alternatively, create an update that does not contain the files you don't want in the `\assets` directory