# Creating and deleting a file in assets folder automatically

Tags: android, android-file, android-assets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how we can remove a file from the assets folder at runtime in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398523/how-we-can-remove-a-file-from-the-assets-folder-at-runtime-in-android)

Is it possible to create a file in assets folder when an application is run and delete the same file when the app is stopped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**For `assets`, you have read file permission *only*.**

So you cannot create/delete files in the `assets` directory. Following are the restrictions applied to `assets` directory.

1. Only Read Permission available for this directory.
2. File size for placing inside the `assets` limit to 10 MB. If you want to place then the larger file should be placed as chunk.
3. You can use this directory for placing files like database file, font file etc...

Don't fight with it. It is not a proper way of dealing with files using the `assets` directory.

You can use SDcard as a suitable location for creating and deleting files

You can use standard method for placing files in SDcard through app,

```
 Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("filetype");
```

Answer (score 3):

The apk is read only and the assets/ folder is not modifiable at runtime, which sounds like something you may be seeking. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398523/how-we-can-remove-a-file-from-the-assets-folder-at-runtime-in-android)