# how to delete sqlite database in mobile

Tags: android, sqlite

When my app starts, it copys sqlite database from assets folder to internal storage. and it works fine, but I need to upgrade my database, in that case, I have to delete my database in user's phone. How can I delete it programmatically? Thank you in advance.

Comment: With the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3406632/9629748) about runtime permission. You can not delete asset resource directly, but you can `upgrade your app with new sqlite database to overwrite the older in asset`.  And you may need to write some codes for migrations of tables change, columns change and others.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I consider your opinion on writing some codes for migration of table change, I am entry level programmer, so I can not think other way not to rerun the migration codes whenever user runs my app, so  I thought it is best to just delete the db inside user's internal storage not from assets. Do you know how to delete db inside user's internal storage?

Comment: You can try `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);`, or if you know the database path, you can delete the .db file directly too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!. I tried with your answer. but it didn't work. My code is like this. getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(ROOT_DIR + "/" + dbName); I think it just erased the content of the file so the size of the file is 0. but the file still exists. so when I run this code    checkDB = new File(ROOT_DIR + "/" + dbName);

            if (!checkDB.exists()) { here it says I have a file even if the size of the file is 0. Do you know any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I tried this code too. and it didn't work...   
                File f = new File(ROOT_DIR + "/" + dbName);
                if(f.delete()){
                    Log.d("deleteFile", "test");
                }
                getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(ROOT_DIR + "/" + dbName); Do you know any other way to resolve this?

Comment: Where is your `ROOT_DIR`, is it not in your app directory such as `data/data/{app_package}/your_database.db`?  You can check it with `DeviceFileExplorer` to find the real-path.

Comment: I googled it and find out i need to used deletefile(dbname) not delete() now it works. Thank you for your comment.